# How to store the function in cache after parse in php

Tags: php

I have a requirement where I need to call the same function again and again in a foreach loop. Is there a way that I could store the function in cache after being compile/interpret for the first time and then call that compiled/interpret function from the cache. So that I could save the time in coding of function interpretation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question because the answer is as basic as it gets: `$result = your_expensive_function();` and then only access `$result`.

Comment: When you include file with your function - it is parsed by php once per request and function can be used anywhere during your request.

Comment: I have different-2 input into the one request. I get different output on the basis of different inputs.